# Queue in C acting strangely after poping all elements

Tags: c, queue

I define my queue like so:

```
struct Node
 {
  int Data;
  struct Node* next;
 }*rear, *front;

int pop()
{
      struct Node *temp, *var=rear;
      int data = var->Data;
      if(var==rear)
      {
             rear = rear->next;
             free(var);
      }
      else{
      printf("\nQueue Empty");
      }
      return data;
}

void push(int value)
{
     struct Node *temp;
     temp=(struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
     temp->Data=value;
     if (front == NULL)
     {
           front=temp;
           front->next=NULL;
           rear=front;
     }
     else
     {
           front->next=temp;
           front=temp;
           front->next=NULL;
     }
}
```

When I pop the last element in the queue, I am unable to push more elements.

Results:

```
1. Push to Queue
2. Pop from Queue
3. Display Data of Queue
4. Exit

5. Empty Choose Option: 1

Enter a valueber to push into Queue: 10
Calling push with 10, temp at 8061420. push done: front = 8061420, rear = 8061420
Elements are as:        10

Choose Option: 1

Enter a valueber to push into Queue: 20
Calling push with 20, temp at 8061430. push done: front = 8061420, rear = 8061430
Elements are as:        20

Choose Option: 2
Elements are as:        20

Choose Option:
```

Comment: Your concept about queue is wrong. In queue insertion is done from rear and poping is done from front. What you are doing is stack.

Comment: The variables may make it seem so but this is not the case in execution. Regardless, this does not begin to answer my question.

Comment: After the second `push` it shows that `front` is one value, and `rear` is another value.  So there are two values in the list.  You need to look at what `front` and `rear` are when you start your `display()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting at the beginning, if you do not set `front` and `rear` somewhere to NULL, then none of this works right.

Then lets look at `push()`:

When the list is empty, you set `front` and `rear` equal to `temp`.  That's good.  When there is a `front` you set `front->next= temp ;`  This is not good if you already added something else in the list.  The idea should be to use `rear` to always point to the last thing added to the list, and always add to the end of `rear`.

So you should do:

```
void push(int value)
{
  struct Node * temp= (struct Node *) malloc( sizeof( struct Node)) ;
  temp-> Data= value ;
  temp-> next= NULL ;
  fprintf(stderr, "Calling push with %d, temp at %lx.\n", value, temp) ;

  if ( rear) { rear-> next= temp ;  rear= temp ; }
    else { front= rear= temp ; }

  fprintf(stderr, "push done: front = %lx, rear = %lx\n", (long) front, (long) rear) ;
}
```

Similarly, you have things a bit backwards on `pop()`.  You look at `rear` and also check `rear->next`.  `rear->next` should **always** be `NULL`.  Instead, just take the first thing off of `front`.  Worse than that though is that you look at the value of `rear` before even checking that its empty.  This is going to do bad things.  So test the pointer for being valid first, then read its value:

```
int pop()
{
  int retval= -1 ;
  if ( front )
  {
    struct Node * temp= front ;
    front= front-> next ;
    if ( ! front ) { rear= front ; }
    retval= temp-> Data ;
    free( temp) ;
  }
  return retval ;
}
```

This should get you operating.
}

Comment: This replaces the first/last every time you push.

Comment: @PandaBearSoup why do you think `first` is replaced every time you `push()` ?

Comment: I've just tested it, nothing is added to the list. I really appreciate your help so far, and understand what you are getting at.

Using this to display list:
void display()
{
     struct Node *var=front;
     if(var!=NULL)
     {
           printf("\nElements are as:  ");
           while(var!=NULL)
           {
                printf("\t%d",var->Data);
                var=var->next;
           }
     printf("\n");
     }
     else
     printf("\nQueue is Empty");
}

Comment: So the first time you call `push()`, it should create a `Node` and then assign it to `front` and `rear`.  Are you saying that this does not happen?

Comment: Make sure you are initializing `front` and `rear` to NULL somewhere.

Comment: This did not affect it unfortunately.

Comment: I've added some `printf`s.  I'd be curious to know what they output.

Comment: I have added my output to the original post.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, I got it working with you and others help, not to mention getting it working in my own mind.